# Serial.write - sedd ascii characters with hex value in the same line

Tags: serial

Working on making a controller for a haunted house prop. Trying to get it to interface with a device.

Was able to use a serial analyzer to see what commands and values are being sent.

the hex codes being sent over serial for manual control is " 40 4d 01" which translates to "@M[?]"

the third byte 01 is the configuration state you want to have it change to. I'm using a byte to store the value between 0-255.

I'm stumped at how to send 2 ASCII characters but in the same Serial.write() command send a raw value, or at how to send them all as hex. I'm sure this is straight forward and I'm just unaware of some simple function.

Comment: hex is just a human representation of binary ... it is easier to write `4d` instead of `01001101` ... it is just a number ... decimal 77

Comment: If you see "@M[?]", which means your are reading it as [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com). `40` hex in ASCII is '@'. You probably send the data correctly if you are using `Serail.write()` but when you read the data with `uint8_t incomingByte = Serial.read()`, the return would be in byte(i.e. uint8_t) instead of char, to see the correct HEX, use `Serial.print(incomingByte, HEX);`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I will challenge your assumption that you have to send the
three bytes in the same call to `Serial.write()`. There is no real
advantage in doing so. Serial output is handled through a memory buffer
that is consumed by the serial port within an interrupt service routine.
`Serial.write()` only writes to that memory buffer. Thus, you can
simply:

```cpp
Serial.write("@M");
Serial.write(1);
```

and the receiver will not see the difference. There will be no gap
between the `'M'` and the `1`. There is no notion of “messages” or
“frames” on a serial link, unless an upper layer protocol adds its own
framing, which is not the case here.

Next, if you really want to issue a single call (futile as this is), you
could

```cpp
Serial.write("@M\1");
```

This, however, will not work if the last byte is zero. The method shown
by the busybee is more general ans is able to send a zero-valued byte.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `byte` array for this:

```cpp
    // at the appropriate place in your code:
    byte message[] = { '@', 'M', 0x01 };
    Serial.write(message, sizeof message);
```

If you need, you can prepare the array and just assign the value:

```cpp
byte message[] = { '@', 'M', 0 };

// ...

    byte value = 0x01; // or any other assignment

    // at the appropriate place in your code:
    message[2] = value;
    Serial.write(message, sizeof message);
```